# Python Pytorch Multiprocessing Pycharm PicklingError: Can't pickle <function train at 0x7f4064696e18>: attribute lookup train on __main__ failed

Tags: python, pytorch, pycharm, multiprocessing

This error happens when running `multiprocessing` (using `spawn` method) in Python or Pytorch (`torch.multiprocessing`) using Pycharm 2021.2.3.

The function `train` is defined at the top level of the module, so it should be pickable. However, the error says that it cannot be pickled.

A simple code may look like this:

```
def train(gpu):
    print(f'hello {gpu}!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.spawn(train, nprocs=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is a bug in Pycharm 2021.2.3 and happens when `Run with Python Console` is checked in run configurations. This bug is being tracked at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50116

This can be resolved using the following two options (until the bug is resolved):

1. Uncheck `Run with Python Console`
2. Downgrade to Pycharm 2021.1.3

Comment: Thanks, this link helps me a lot!